# Incomplete sentences when introducing a table below

Tags: punctuation, sentence, end-punctuation

When writing notes, I've noticed that I write incomplete sentences before a table and I'm not sure where the "full stop" should go and whether I should use a colon.

**Example.**

The parameters used in the pareto distribution are:
[image]

.

Is the colon supposed to be there? And should there be a full stop after the table somewhere?

Comment: You have it right except for the period. Consider the table a big period, or a giant full stop.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Thank you! Is that really a thing - tables and plots can end sentences?

Comment: You could look at it that way. No one else will. Just say no to adding punctuation after a graphic.